# check the files before trigger of jenkins job through SCM poll

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, perforce

I have a freestyle project in jenkins . This job get triggered based on SCM poll. It listens to files say in module A . So whenever anything changes in module A this get triggers.

Now my issue is if the changelist contain other module files in addition to modeule A files , this job gets trigger . I want to control this . I mean this build should not trigger when the changelist contains any other module file along with module A file. whereas it should only get trigger when module A files are present

Comment: what kind of SCM plugin you use? eg: SVN,GIT etc

Comment: I use Perforce Plugin

Answer (score 0):

you could try "Additional Behaviours"->"polling ignores certain paths" in git plugin.

Comment: He talked about Perforce, not Git